# Node js connection to Oracle DB gives DPI-1047

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB to node JS. SQL developer is already installed and working successfully, SQL developer is connected to server database using tnsnames.ora file. But when i try to run below code

```
    oracledb.getConnection({
    user          : "Admin",
    password      : "Password",
    connectString : "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = 
    xx.xx.xx.xx)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED) 
    (SERVICE_NAME = sblbld)))"})
```

```
it throws below error:
Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\app\product\1
1.1.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://oracle.
github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/
INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from.
```

Could someone pls help.
Thanks

Comment: Why not click the links in the error message and follow the instructions?

Comment: Your code is not using a tnsnames.ora file since you have the connection string hardcoded.  You could use an alias from a tnsnames.ora file if you wanted.  See the node-oracledb documentation: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#tnsnames

Comment: The latest node-oracledb 6.0 doesn't always need Instant Client so you won't see DPI-1047 (as long as your code doesn't call `initOracleClient()`), see the [release announcement](https://medium.com/@sharad-chandran/usher-in-a-new-era-with-the-node-oracledb-6-0-pure-javascript-thin-driver-e10e2af693b2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason SQL Developer does not complain about the same problem as your node.js app is SQL Developer is using a pure Java JDBC driver to connect to the database. The JDBC *thin driver* is entirely written in Java and is included in the installation of the product "SQL Developer".

You should get a similar error message if you ask SQL Developer to connect to the database using a *thick driver* (OCI library)

There are situations where you will need the thick driver to connect in SQL Developer. This link will explain when:
https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/04/sql-developer-19-1-connections-thick-or-thin/

Your node.js oracledb module requires a client side library (OCI) in order to connect to the database so please download and install an oracle instant client before any connections are tried.

Best of luck